# JTable Row-Editor

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm searching for an editor like in [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor) example; I mean the "Pick a Color"-Frame, but for the whole row. Is it my issue to fully implement this, or can I expand some exsiting editors?

Comment: You can specify one editor for each data type in your table, using the JTable `setDefaultEditor` method.

Comment: What do you mean with "for the hole row"?

Comment: something like an child window, with some textfileds/checkboxes, instead of an editor for one cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default renderers and editors for common column data types are shown [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender). An editor is chosen for any cell in any row for which `isCellEditable()` returns `true`. You can also specify a custom renderer and editor, such as the color chooser you cited. Two recent examples are seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14470230/230513), but the details depend on your use-case.

Addendum: *something like an child window*

You can pass a reference to the table's `TableModel` and the desired row number to your `RowEditor`. You'll have full access to the table model's methods, including `getValueAt()`, `setValueAt()` and `getColumnClass()` methods.

Comment: you mean i have to extend the default rendere to implement my own "RowEditor"

Comment: Not necessarily. "In [`SimpleTableDemo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#eg), all cells are editable." I've elaborated above on your comment about a child window.

Comment: i know, but i would like an popup with textfileds for entering new values for all cell in this specific row.

Comment: You might try a `JOptionPane`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3002830/230513).

Comment: do i need the hole `TableModel` or is the `TabelColumnModel` enough?

Comment: The data is in the `TableModel`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the entire row, with columns A, B, C edited in a new child window as

```
A  ____
B  ____
C  ____
```

Then maybe you could make the row of some bean class Record, and use a java.beans.PropertyEditor to start with.