# Display an icon in a specific JTable cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, icons

I want to display an icon in a specific `JTable` cell, and not have the same icon in the whole column's cells.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows what you've tried, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14470230/230513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've done your [research](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and know how to use [custom cell renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer), the basic concept is simple.

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
                        JTable table, Object color,
                        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                        int row, int column) {
    // Prepare renderer as usual...

    // Check to see if the current row/column is within 
    // the acceptable range...
    // It would be usful if this information was coming from
    // some kind of model
    if (row == iconRow && column == iconColumn) {
        // Apply the icon for this cell renderer
    }
    return this;
}
```